# How is it possible to make curved bar chart or curved column charts in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, jscharts

We are trying to create curved column similar to the image below, it doesnt look possible in chart.js

[image: Cured Barchart]

Any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a `line` chart as illustrated in below code sample, which needs to be further improved to obtain the result you expect.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        datasets: [
          {
              data: [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.7)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.7)',
              lineTension: 0.4,
              pointHitRadius: 0
          },
          {
              data: [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,165,0, 0.7)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,165,0, 0.7)',
              lineTension: 0.6,
              pointHitRadius: 0
          },
          {
              data: [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0, 0.7)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0, 0.7)',
              lineTension: 0.6,
              pointHitRadius: 0
          },
          {
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(59, 161, 151, 0.7)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(59, 161, 151, 0.7)',
              lineTension: 0.6,
              pointHitRadius: 0
          },
          {
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 100, 100, 0.7)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 100, 100, 0.7)',
              lineTension: 0.4,
              pointHitRadius: 0
          }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
          point:{
            radius: 0
          }
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                 display: false
               },
               gridLines: {
                 display: false
               }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                 display: false
               },
               gridLines: {
                 display: false
               }
            }],
        }
    }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```